# Exportar campo que contiene comas (,) de MYSQL a Excel con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, exportar

La consulta la hice así:

```
SELECT facturas FROM facturacion WHERE cliente = 'Cliente1';
```

Al realizar la consulta slq usando phpMyAdmin, lo presenta bien:
 `0617032868,31044737`

Pero al exportar a Excel con PHP, el resultado en la celda aparece:
`61,703,286,831,044,700`

En la barra de fórmulas de Excel aparece:
`61703286831044700`

Pero lo necesito así:
`0617032868,31044737`

La base de datos esta en cotejamiento `utf8mb4_spanish2_ci`

El campo de la tabla: `varchar(100) utf8mb4_spanish2_ci`. Esta en `varchar` por que hay facturas que son alfanuméricas.

Para exportar a Excel desde PHP use:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'; charset=utf-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Archivo'.time().'.xls');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

if (!isset($con))
    {    
        $con = conBD();                   
    }                     
$sql = "SELECT factura,
            FROM facturas
            WHERE cliente ='Cliente1'";
        $ts = mysqli_query($con, $sql) 
                or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ts);
        $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($ts);

        print_r($total_rows);
       
?>
    <tr>
        <th>FACTURA</th>
    </tr>

<?php if ($total_rows > 0) {
        do {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo utf8_decode ($row['factura']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            } while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ts) );
            mysqli_free_result($ts);
        } else {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">NO FUERON ENCONTRADOS DATOS DEL PARAMETRO.</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
```

De antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Realice la modificación sugerida por Triby (por cierto, muchas gracias), no sé si refería a realizar esto en la línea de código que corresponde a la columna:

```
        <td>'<?php echo utf8_decode ($row['factura']); ?></td>
```

Ahora aparece el resultado, digamos casi en el formato esperado:

`'0617032868,31044737`

¿Hay alguna forma de que no aparezca la apostrofe?

Comment: El interprete que convierte tu código html a un archivo de Excel es el que está definiendo el valor como numérico, sería mejor no enviar código html y enviar el archivo binario xlsx , la librería de PhpSpreadsheet lo hace muy bien https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Por lo que veo, realmente no estás construyendo un xls, por mucho que le pongas esa extensión. Tienes a tu disposición muchas librerías para convertir a excel que lo hacen realmente bien.

Comment: Para que Excel interprete el valor como cadena y no como número, agrega un apóstrofe al inicio `'` de la columna.

Comment: Tabitha, gracias por el dato checare la documentación.

Comment: Óscar Novás, gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Triby, ¿Dónde es que se tiene que poner el apostrofe, en el código o directamente en el archivo de Excel?, perdona mi ignorancia pero como te darás cuenta soy muy novato. ¿Puedes darme un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Buen Día

Te comento que no le has definido muy bien al formato que es una fila y columna proveniente de una tabla, también te está faltando el body y el tbody.

Aquí el código según tu ejemplo:

```
<?php
// APLICANDO EN EL HEADER EL FORMATO EXCEL
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Arch_Eventos_MTDS.xls"');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color:#0191CE color:#FFFFFF;">FACTURA</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
<?php

if (!isset($con))
    {    
        $con = conBD();                   
    }                     
    
  
$sql = "SELECT factura,
                    
            FROM facturas
            
            WHERE cliente ='Cliente1'
                ";


 
        $ts = mysqli_query($con, $sql) 
                or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ts);
        $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($ts);

        print_r($total_rows);
       
?>
      <?php if ($total_rows > 0) {
        do {
?>

    <tr>
        
        <td><?php echo utf8_decode ($row['factura']); ?></td>
        
    </tr>
    <?php
            } while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ts) );
            mysqli_free_result($ts);
        } else {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">NO FUERON ENCONTRADOS DATOS DEL PARAMETRO.</td>
        </tr>

    <?php 
        } 
    ?>      

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la observación y el apunte, lo tomare en cuenta.